# Firebase/Futter user.displayName field stored as null when storing on cloud-firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building an app using Flutter and Firebase. I am trying to create a user profile on their first login to the app. I am using the Google sign-in method provided by Firebase authentication.

This is my code for the same:

```dart
void _handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    try {
      GoogleAuthProvider googleAuthProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithProvider(googleAuthProvider);
      User? user = userCredential.user;

      // check if user pf exists
      if (user != null) {
        DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .get();

        // if not there, then create
        if (!userDoc.exists) {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc(user.uid)
              .set(
            {
              "photoUrl": user.photoURL,
              "displayName": user.displayName,
              "email": user.email,
            },
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(e.toString()),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

I am storing `displayName`, `photoUrl`, `email`, and other fields (still thinking). But on the Firestore window, it shows that the document was stored with `displayName` set to `null`.

[image: null field]

So what am I doing wrong, and what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

The Display Name will be null when you create the user, You need to update it adter creating the user

```
_auth.currentUser.updateDisplayName('Insert the name here');
```

Comment: In general, sign-in methods apart from anonymous and email-password methods do provide displayName. So there is no need to update the existing one. In my case, I am using google sign in

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Firebase Authentication with Google, most likely you should read the [username](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AdditionalUserInfo/username.html) field that exists inside the [AdditionalUserInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AdditionalUserInfo-class.html) class. So in code, it should be something like this:

```
UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithProvider(googleAuthProvider);
String username = userCredential.additionalUserInfo.username;
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?